# fileowner show "0" what it is mean(no wner)

Tags: php, filesystems

when I run the below code, I got error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function posix_getpwuid()"  in line `$owner = posix_getpwuid($uid);`.

1. why?
2. does that means there's no owner when `$uid=0`?

I know that `$uid=0`

```
$logfile = 'log.txt';
    echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($logfile)), -4)."<br />";
    $uid = fileowner($logfile);
    if ($uid === false) die("Could not determine file owner!");
    $owner = posix_getpwuid($uid);
    echo "The file owner's name is " . $owner[name] . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says: There is no such function `posix_getpwuid()`.

However, since [there obviously is](http://php.net/posix-getpwuid), POSIX functions must be disabled on your server. Contact your host to find out if this is the case and why.

I believe a UID of 0 indicates the root user, but I don't know enough about filesystems to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the `posix` extension is not installed or enabled on your system.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. why?

Either your platform doesn't support it, or it wasn't compiled.

> 2. ...

UID 0 is `root`.

Comment: where can I see the table value of UID 0 = root ? Thanks